# Difference between for and while loops in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

hey so i just started programming (C) and i wanna know the difference between while and for loops, so i did a program to sum natural numbers with a for loop and it worked:

```
int sum = 0;
int count;
int num = 11;

for (count = 1; count <= num; count++){
    sum += count;
}
printf("Sum of numbers is: %d\n", sum);
```

Sum came out as 66 and count comes out as 11, but when i tried it in a while loop it came out wrong:

```
int kount = 1;
int ssum = 0;
int number = 11;
while(kount <= number){
    ++kount;
    ssum += kount;
}
printf("Ssum is: %d \n", ssum);
printf("Kount is %d \n", kount);
```

Here ssum comes out as 77 and kount comes out as 12. Can anyone explain why to a beginner like me?

Comment: Hey! Check the value of `count` / `kount` when you add to the sum!

Comment: `++kount; ssum += kount;` Change the order of these to get for-loop-like behavior.

Comment: the value of count goes to 11 while  the value of kount in the while code comes out as 12 and i have no idea why?

Comment: Changing the order worked! Can you explain why that happens?

Comment: `for` loops perform third statement, `count++`, after loop has completed (i.e. at end).

Comment: An alternative would be to initialize `kount` to `0` and change you're while loop to `while(kount < number)`.

Comment: `for(a;b;c){d;}` is broadly equivalent to `a;while(b){d;c;}` -- note the relative order of `c` and `d` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference between for and while loop is all three steps initalization, test and increment are written in single line.

**For loop:**

```
int a ;
for(a= 0; a<10; a++)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

---

**While loop:**

```
int a = 0;     // 1. Initialization step
while (a < 10) // 2. Test step
{
    // Do something
    a++;      // 3.Increment step. a++ is the same as saying a=a+1, 
}
```

Another way of comparing two numbers in while loop:

```
a=2;
b=3;
while (a < b)
{
    a++;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

You can do this in one-liner using for loop.

```
for (a=2,b=3; a < b; a++,printf("%d\n",a));
```

Comment: edit the x ni the `for loop`

Answer (score 2):

just add line ++Kount after ssum+=kount and your problem will get solved.

```
int ssum = 0;
int kount = 1;
int number = 11;
while (kount <= number) {
    ssum += kount;
    ++kount;

}
printf("Ssum is: %d \n", ssum);
printf("Kount is %d \n", kount);
```

Comment: console.log() is not C.

Comment: oops i executed this code in node.js so you can replace console.log with printf.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the body of your while loop try doing

`ssum += kount;` 
before you do `++kount;`

Answer (score 0):

For safety reasons, it is often recommended to use for-loops instead of while.

With for-loops you have an "automatic" maximum loop count. When using while this depends on your code in the while-loop.

This is specially important on microcontrollers where your programm will get stuck if you do not leave the loop implementation.